# In Postfix, Should SSL FQDN Matches with myhostname or mydomain field in /etc/postfix/main.cf?

Tags: postfix, smtp, openssl, lets-encrypt, smtp-auth

Quoted from [the documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html):

> **myhostname**
>
> The internet hostname of this mail system. The default is to use the fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) from gethostname(), or to use the non-FQDN result from gethostname() and append ".$mydomain". $myhostname is used as a default value for many other configuration parameters.

> **mydomain**
>
> The internet domain name of this mail system. The default is to use $myhostname minus the first component, or "localdomain" (Postfix 2.3 and later). $mydomain is used as a default value for many other configuration parameters.

I'm confused that FQDN postfix should be equivalent as SSL FQDN or not. For now, let's assume `/etc/postfix/main.cf` configuration is

```
myhostname = mail.pelersapi.id
mydomain = pelersapi.id
myorigin = $mydomain
```

Now the question is: **can I create a SSL certificate with domain mail.pelersapi.id while keep the sales@pelersapi.id address valid?**

Currently, I'm using Let's Encrypt to make the certificate

```
sudo certbot certonly                                                            \
    --dns-cloudflare                                                             \
    --dns-cloudflare-credentials /etc/letsencrypt/cloudflare/pelersapi.id.ini    \
    --dns-cloudflare-propagation-seconds 30                                      \
    -d mail.pelersapi.id                                                         \
    -m admin@pelersapi.id
```

My previous attempt was keeping SSL FQDN and `myhostname` same as `mydomain`, then it's successfully authenticated. For the scenario explained above, I'm afraid misunderstanding the theory could causes spam score worsen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `mail.pelersapi.id` is defined in DNS as the MX for `pelersapi.id`, and if there is an A record that points `mail.pelersapi.id` at your Postfix server, then having a certificate for `mail.pelersapi.id` on that server will validate all mail addresses `x@pelersapi.id`. (If there is a second mailer `mail2.pelersapi.id` it will need a certificate for itself, of course.)

Comment: Okay, then the DNS Server should be configured as `MX record of pelersapi.id to mail.pelersapi.id` and `A record of mail.pelersapi.id to 117.53.231.34` right? Thanks for the concisely helpful clue!

Comment: Yes. The only other tip is that you need to set a priority in your MX record; 10 is a good value for that. (Priority is used to allow for additional, failover mail servers; lower-numbered servers are used first, and higher-numbered ones if the low-numbered ones don't respond.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in simple cases like this, you want the SSL certificate to contain `mail.pelersapi.id`, just like `myhostname`. The fact that this happens to be a subdomain of your mail domain is just a bonus.

Remember this certificate is presented when you are *receiving* messages. People you are sending messages to do not see this (they use SPF/DKIM/DMARC to establish sender authority). Your cert presented on your MX only even starts to matter as they reply (or bounce).

---

Look for the [separate manual page, or possibly a text document](https://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls_verify) in `/usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README` referenced from that documentation, specifically for the TLS related discussions:

> DNS names in the SubjectAlternativeName certificate extension are used
> to verify the remote **SMTP server name**

If you read through that explanation you will see, it used to be and still is quite a bit more complicated than just that, but a configuration that covers most of the edge cases is not that complicated: MX record, `$myhostname` match and appear in `SAN.DNSName` of the certificate, which is signed by some Mozilla-trusted CA just like any website certificate, done.

Comment: So in a nutshell, SSL is just for receiving and SPF/DKIM/DMARC are for sending mail? Anyway, thanks for the additional information!